# Location Based Bandwidth Throttling In Live Update?

Tags: bandwidth, throttling, sep

In Symantec Endpoint Protection 12.1.4 (RU4), we've been having an issue with Live Update smashing the links to our smaller sites. I've done a bit of digging around Symantec's site, but can't figure out how to implement location based throttling of the Live Update services.

I have the I.P. ranges of the smaller sites I'd like to use, and have entered them in as locations, but do not know where to apply them (at the 'My Company' level?) or how to do it.